SAS boxplots: how to plot simultaneously two set of data?
I have three variables: SFT_R (continuous variable relative to the right eye), SFT_L (same variable, but relative to the left eye) and age_cod (age quartiles categorized as 0,1,2,3).
For each quartile I would like to have R and L values.
Is there a way to plot the boxplots of the two variables (SFT_R and SFT_L), side by side, by age quartiles without reshape the database creating a new grouping variable "eye_side"?
I tried with:
proc sgplot data=zero;
hbox SFT_R / category=age_cod LEGENDLABEL="SFT R";
hbox SFT_L / category=age_cod LEGENDLABEL="SFT L";
run;


but boxplots were overlapped:

Any ideas?

I think you need to reshape the data :(

You can do it by adding the discreteoffset option to one (or both plots), which will shift them a bit.  But it's a bit of wonky trial-and-error.  I would typically reshape the data so that you just have one variable to plot, and then can use Left vs Right as the groups.
The discreteoffset would look like:
proc sgplot data=zero;
  hbox SFT_R / category=age_cod LEGENDLABEL="SFT R" discreteoffset=.5;
  hbox SFT_L / category=age_cod LEGENDLABEL="SFT L";
run;

